# Kotlin type inference for multiple possible types?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that takes parameter `metadata` of two possible types: Metadata1 or Metadata2. I'm trying to write a utility function that can be used for both since there is a ton of code reuse. Both of them have a list of DataPoint objects, each of which has name() method.

I thought in my code Kotlin would use type inference to know that `dataPoints` can only be one of two types that both have DataPoint.name() method, but I'm getting "unresolved reference: name". How can I make this function generic enough to apply to both Metadata1 and Metadata2?

```
var dataPoints: List<Any>
if (metadata is Metadata1) {
    dataPoints = metadata.metadata1().dataPoints()
} else {
    dataPoints = (metadata as Metadata2).metadata2().dataPoints()
}
if (data.size > 1) {
    textView.test = dataPoints.fold("")
    { x, dataPoint ->
        x + dataPoint.name() + " \n" // unresolved reference: name
    }
}
```

Comment: No, Kotlin doesn't have union types. Plus you declared a `List<Any>`. Do these two classes have a common interface or super class?

Comment: You should create an interface (with a `name()` function defined, for example) that both classes implement.

Comment: `Metadata1` and `Metadata2` _must_ have some shared supertype: an interface, a class, a sealed class (which would guarantee it's always one of those two)...Without that, there's basically nothing you can do to make this work.  (Well, you could create a sealed class that holds either a `Metadata1` or a `Metadata2`, but that adds more work at the caller's side.)

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by mapping dataPoints to a single, shared type for both Metadata1 and Metadata2 and passing that directly into the function as shared type parameter. Thanks all!

Comment: Both classes may have a method _called_ `name()`, but it's only the same method if they inherit from the same class or interface.  Otherwise, they're completely different, unrelated methods that just happen to be spelled the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't unique to Kotlin, statically typed OOP languages work like this.

Your dataPoints is of type `List<Any>` and `Any` does not have a name() function. You're not showing a lot of code so I can't tell what kind of objects you have.

This is about run-time vs compile-time. The compiler can't predict what types you're going to put into your `List<Any>` at runtime and so the only functions you can call on its members are functions that belong to the `Any` class. Imagine if that list contained an object that didn't have a name() function. If the compiler allowed you to call name() then you'd have a run-time crash. This is why you get a compiler-time error when you try.

If you have two different types of objects that goes in the list, one way would be to make an interface that they both implement with shared methods in the interface. Which would look something like this:

```
interface Name {
    fun name()
}
```

Change dataPoints to `List<Name>`, have your data classes implement that, and now `dataPoint.name()` compiles because the only objects allowed in the list are objects of type `Name` with a name() function.

```
var dataPoints: List<Name>
if (metadata is Metadata1) {
    dataPoints = metadata.metadata1().dataPoints()
} else {
    dataPoints = (metadata as Metadata2).metadata2().dataPoints()
}
if (data.size > 1) {
    textView.test = dataPoints.fold("")
    { x, dataPoint ->
        x + dataPoint.name() + " \n" // Compiles now
    }
}
```

You have a similar problem with your Metadata1 and Metadata2 classes, they should probably implement an interface or extend a super class.